# CSS decoration - fill the cyrcles of the letters

Tags: css, text-decorations

Is it possible to fill the cyrcles in letters like "p", "o", "g", etc?!? It looks like a fun text-decoration.

Edit: with no custom font, just css.

Comment: It may be a silly question. I found an old encyclopedia, from my childhood and on some pages I had filled the circles. It tought how a page will look like, if the same happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this in CSS. The only possible way to reach your goal is to find a font with pre-filled letters.

Maybe you could find one here: http://www.dafont.com/

Once you've found one, you could load it using the CSS3 feature:

```
@font-face
{
   font-family: myFont;
   src: url('your_font.otf');
}
```

Then you could refer to it directly:

```
h1
{
   font-family: myFont;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but you'll have to make your font. It also will not work in every browser.  Check out the [CSS 3 Fonts module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/).

Update: Here is [another helpful link from A List Apart on Web Fonts](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fonts-at-the-crossing/).